# gridview attribute modified by javascript is lost on postback

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview control that extends the default gridview.  I have added an attribute called "hiddenSelectedValues" to to the gridview during the "PreRender" event and I have a private variable that points to the value of that attribute.

I have some javascript code that modifies the value of this attribute based on the user checking or unchecking checkboxes in the grid.  I have confirmed that the javascript is indeed modifying the value of the "hiddenSelectedValues" attribute by using Firebug to see the change as it happens.

However, once a postback occurs, the grid looses the updated value of this attribute and I am unable to reference get the updated value on the server side.

How do I keep the value of an attribute changed by javascript on postback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a hidden filed. That's because no attributes are passed on the request back to the web server.

---

***Added in reply to comment.***

You can accomplish this using hidden fields INSIDE the row without problems. Simply give the hidden fields the same `NAME` attribute and use `Request["<name>"].Split(",")` to retrieve an array of values on the post-back.

Comment: Well I originally tried using a hiddenfield but since this is a gridview control I had to put the hiddenfield in one of the rows (header, footer, pager, etc).  Then the problem arose that I need to access the value of the hiddenfield prior to the rows being created, so I had to get the value out of the rows and somewhere else, and I thought creating a new attribute and storing the value there would work.  Any suggestions as to how to get around this?